# What is the background music to this horrible little video?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I apologise for the video, which I am not promoting in any way, but the piece of music used as the the soundtrack is sooo familiar, I just can't get the name. https://m.facebook.com/watch/?v=325029343816278&extid=CL-UNK-UNK-UNK-AN_GK0T-GK1C&ref=sharing&mibextid=CDWPTG&wtsid=rdr_0QBxoIM6MWvtcyE0s

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

[Danse Macabre, Op. 40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdrR9L_A_Wg)

You can use Google app in your phone.
it has "identify any song feature"